# jQuery - Random image generator (fix my code,maybe only syntax errors)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Welcome again,I have some problems with my code.
I still want to get random() background images,but
I can't get it working. It show the default white background with the two text 'title'. :(
My files are => in extension '.jpg' and in directory '/res/images' what's wrong?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Random_page</title>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

  //the highest number of the image you want to load
  var upperLimit = 10;

  //get random number between 1 and 10
  //change upperlimit above to increase or 
  //decrease range
  var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * upperLimit) + 1);    


  //change the background image to a random jpg
  //edit add closing )  to prevent syntax error
  $("body").css("background-image","url('res/images/" + randomNum + ".jpg')");//<--changed path

  });
  </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container1" style="float:left; width:40%; margin:10px;">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <img src="" width='100%' height='100%' />
        </div>
        <div id="container2" style="float:left; width:40%; margin: 10px;">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <img src="" width='100%' height='100%' />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer console says:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

It means jQuery didn't load. Actual reason is missing `http:`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Uh,what a mistake. Thank you. :O